# ActiveAdmin has_many display partial conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a **Table1** who has a has_many relation with **Table2**.

**Code 1** :-

```
## _edit_table1.html.erb

<% f.has_many :table2_relations, heading: false, new_record: true, allow_destroy: true do |r| %>
  <%= render partial: "admin/table1/show/form_table2", locals: { r: r } %>
<% end %>
```

I want to display the partial based on attribute0 of **Table2**, which is a boolean. Only if attribute0 is true, I want to display the partial.
I tried :

**Code 2** :-

```
## _edit_table1.html.erb

<% f.has_many :table2_relations, heading: false, new_record: true, allow_destroy: true do |r| %>
  <% if r.object.attribute0 %>
    <%= render partial: "admin/table1/show/form_table2", locals: { r: r } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Output of code1 is :

[image]

Output of code2 is :

[image]

I don't know how to remove the second box which only has Delete on it... I only want the first box which has ID 2 and delete tick. 
Thank you

Comment: If you put in a `binding.pry` what is the output of `r.object` and `r.object.attribute0`? The code you put in should be properly checking the object's attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a relation that excludes the records you don't need.

```
class Table1
  has_many :table2s
  has_many :active_table2s, -> {where(attribute0: true)}, class_name: 'Table2'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :active_table2s ...
```

Then use that relation instead of the all inclusive one